# Sticky section scrolling effect HTML

Tags: javascript, html, css

In the following [pen](https://codepen.io/ZenHundred/pen/bGVMBaWP) I would like to create an effect where you have to scroll (by scrolling, not with mouse movement), all the way down until the top image is revealed, until we move to the next section.

The effect I'm trying to re-create, in case the explanation is too confusing can be found on Apple's website [here](https://www.apple.com/imac-pro/)

As you scroll down you'll understand.

```
  let wrapper = document.querySelector('#wrapper');
  let topLayer = wrapper.querySelector('.top');
  let handle = wrapper.querySelector('.handle');

  wrapper.addEventListener('mousemove', e => {
    handle.style.top = e.clientY + 'px';

    topLayer.style.height = e.clientY + 'px';
  });
});
```

Comment: You need to use the CSS `position:sticky`. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example using the CSS `position: sticky`

```css
body {
  font-family: georgia;
  height: 1000px;
}

img {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.sticky {
  position: sticky;
  position: -webkit-sticky;
  width: 100%;
  top: 25vh;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  color: #fff;
}

.wrapper {
  width: 75%;
  margin: auto;
  background-color: silver;
  padding: 15px;
}

.wrapper {
  height: 200vh;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.6.0/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="wrapper bg-primary">
  <div class="sticky">
    <img src='https://dummyimage.com/400x100.png?text=image-1' alt='' />
  </div>
</div>
<br>
<div class="wrapper bg-success">
  <div class="sticky">
    <img src='https://dummyimage.com/400x100.png?text=image-2' alt='' />
  </div>
</div>
<br>
<div class="wrapper bg-warning">
  <div class="sticky">
    <img src='https://dummyimage.com/400x100.png?text=image-3' alt='' />
  </div>
</div>
```